# Add a row to a table in Excel With VB

Tags: vba, excel

I have been looking everywhere for an answer to this questions and either I haven't been able to find one or I am not understanding the answers I do find.

I have a workbook in Excel 2013.  I am using VBA to add some drop down lists and forms to the workbook to make it easy to fill out.

One of the user forms I have, has a few data entry fields, and when you click "Add" it adds the information to the last row of the table.

Here is the code for that User Form;

```
Private Sub Add_Click()

Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
Dim table_list_object As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow
Set the_sheet = Sheets("Structural")
Set table_list_object = the_sheet.ListObjects(1)
Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add

table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = "Deck"

last_row_with_data = the_sheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

the_sheet.Range("B" & last_row_with_data) = TextBox3
the_sheet.Range("C" & last_row_with_data) = TextBox4
the_sheet.Range("D" & last_row_with_data) = ComboBox1

Unload Me
End Sub
```

Again this works perfectly and does exactly what I need it to do.

I have another user form that I need to input data in and have it put the data in a row in the table.  But I can not figure out how to make it add data to anything but the last row.

Right now I have a macro that runs when you click the "Add" button;

```
Sub AddRow6Sheet3()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Rows("7:7").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This works great for adding a row at row 7, which is where I need the data to go. But I need the data to then get input into the new row 7 that got created.  This form will always input into row 7.

But I would also like to know how to just add data to any row.  Because later in the workbook I'm going to run into a similar problem.

Comment: [this reference may come in handy](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Scott, that didn't exactly answer my question.  But there is a ton of useful information in there and one of the things on that link did give me an idea, which ended up being what I needed.  The code that works is as follows 
Private Sub Add_Click()

```
Call AddRow6Sheet3
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table13").ListRows.Add (7)
    With Sheets("Misc Metals")
    .Range("B7").Value = Me.ComboBox5.Value
    .Range("C7").Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    .Range("D7").Value = Me.ComboBox2.Value
    .Range("E7").Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value
    .Range("F7").Value = Me.ComboBox4.Value
    .Range("G7").Value = Me.ComboBox6.Value
End With
Unload MeEnd Sub
```

I'm still playing with if I need both the Macro and the ListRows.Add line.  I know it doesn't work right without the macro.  It just seems to overwrite what is in row 7.

Thanks